# Getting word embeddings using XLNet?

Tags: python, nlp, data-mining, word2vec, glove

Hello I have been trying to contextual extract word embedding using the novel XLNet but without luck.

Running on Google Colab with TPU

I would like to note that I get this error when I use TPU so thus I switch to GPU to avoid the error

```
xlnet_config = xlnet.XLNetConfig(json_path=FLAGS.model_config_path)
```

> AttributeError: module 'xlnet' has no attribute 'XLNetConfig'

However I get another error when I use GPU

```
run_config = xlnet.create_run_config(is_training=True, is_finetune=True, FLAGS=FLAGS)
```

> AttributeError: use_tpu

I will post the whole code below: I am using a small sentence as an input till it work and I switch to big data then

**Main Code:**

```
import sentencepiece as spm
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf
from prepro_utils import preprocess_text, encode_ids
import xlnet
import sentencepiece as spm

text = "The metamorphic rocks of western Crete form a series some 9000 to 10,000 ft."
sp_model = spm.SentencePieceProcessor()
sp_model.Load("/content/xlnet_cased_L-24_H-1024_A-16/spiece.model")

text = preprocess_text(text) 
ids = encode_ids(sp_model, text)

#print('ids',ids)

# some code omitted here...
# initialize FLAGS
# initialize instances of tf.Tensor, including input_ids, seg_ids, and input_mask

# XLNetConfig contains hyperparameters that are specific to a model checkpoint.
xlnet_config = xlnet.XLNetConfig(json_path=FLAGS.model_config_path) **ERROR 1 HERE**
from absl import flags
import sys

FLAGS = flags.FLAGS
# RunConfig contains hyperparameters that could be different between pretraining and finetuning.
run_config = xlnet.create_run_config(is_training=True, is_finetune=True, FLAGS=FLAGS) **ERROR 2 HERE**
xp = []
xp.append(ids)
input_ids = np.asarray(xp)
xlnet_model = xlnet.XLNetModel(
    xlnet_config=xlnet_config,
    run_config=run_config,
    input_ids=input_ids,
    seg_ids=None,
    input_mask=None)
embed1=tf.train.load_variable('../data/xlnet_cased_L-24_H-1024_A-16/xlnet_model.ckpt','model/transformer/word_embedding/lookup_table:0')`
```

**Before the main code I'm cloning Xlnet from GitHub and so on (I will also post it)**

```
! pip install sentencepiece
#Download the pretrained XLNet model and unzip only needs to be done once
! wget https://storage.googleapis.com/xlnet/released_models/cased_L-24_H-1024_A-16.zip
! unzip cased_L-24_H-1024_A-16.zip
! git clone https://github.com/zihangdai/xlnet.git

SCRIPTS_DIR = 'xlnet' #@param {type:"string"}
DATA_DIR = 'aclImdb' #@param {type:"string"}
OUTPUT_DIR = 'proc_data/imdb' #@param {type:"string"}
PRETRAINED_MODEL_DIR = 'xlnet_cased_L-24_H-1024_A-16' #@param {type:"string"}
CHECKPOINT_DIR = 'exp/imdb' #@param {type:"string"}

train_command = "python xlnet/run_classifier.py \
  --do_train=True \
  --do_eval=True \
  --eval_all_ckpt=True \
  --task_name=imdb \
  --data_dir="+DATA_DIR+" \
  --output_dir="+OUTPUT_DIR+" \
  --model_dir="+CHECKPOINT_DIR+" \
  --uncased=False \
  --spiece_model_file="+PRETRAINED_MODEL_DIR+"/spiece.model \
  --model_config_path="+PRETRAINED_MODEL_DIR+"/xlnet_config.json \
  --init_checkpoint="+PRETRAINED_MODEL_DIR+"/xlnet_model.ckpt \
  --max_seq_length=128 \
  --train_batch_size=8 \
  --eval_batch_size=8 \
  --num_hosts=1 \
  --num_core_per_host=1 \
  --learning_rate=2e-5 \
  --train_steps=4000 \
  --warmup_steps=500 \
  --save_steps=500 \
  --iterations=500"

! {train_command}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check this [gist](https://colab.research.google.com/gist/amansrivastava17/c7b7c5e9902133174b4ef6d8587b34b1/embedding-as-service.ipynb#scrollTo=NQEqcqa5v7hg) out.

We have made it really easy to get token level embeddings from `XLNet`

Update: [Updated gist](https://colab.research.google.com/gist/ashutoshsingh0223/d6d673a942dd15546fc28e9fce875b51/embedding-as-service.ipynb) .

For detailed documentation and more examples check [Github](https://github.com/amansrivastava17/embedding-as-service)

Comment: Yes XLNet gives you contextual embeddings through language modeling.
Happy to help...please accept the answer and do give a star to our repo..it would be a great help.

Comment: update: 
 from embedding_as_service.text.encode import Encoder
instead of : from models.encode import Encoder

Comment: Yes we have made a new release. In the next release we will have most of these models as trainable layers!!

Comment: I am currently using your existing one in a project I hope that this version remains unchanged so my project continues working 

Comment: You don't have to worry

Comment: Thanks Ashutosh, does it output word embeddings of the last layer or layers? if it is just the last layer, can we also get word embedding for the hidden layers as well (i.e. last four layers)?

Comment: Yes this output is from the last layer. Its possible to get outputs from intermediate layers as well. It is not implemented there yet though. Which model are you talking about?

Comment: Im using xlnet and bert.

Comment: Check this [gist](https://colab.research.google.com/gist/ashutoshsingh0223/d6d673a942dd15546fc28e9fce875b51/embedding-as-service.ipynb). Look for title `Get outputs from intermediate layers from BERT`

Comment: Hi Ashutosh, I'm trying to get similarities of sentences using your module, but seems like it's not working well. I tested even for single words like 'USA' and 'America'. Similar sentences exhibit no difference than non-similar ones. Is your xlnet model pre-trained or not? Thanks.

Comment: Yes, it is the pre-trained one.  Can you post a snippet of your code here?

Comment: `from embedding_as_service.text.encode import Encoder
xlnet_en = Encoder(embedding='xlnet', model='xlnet_large_cased', max_seq_length=256)

s1 = "He repeatedly spoke about the benefits of spending the summer"
s2 = "He repeatedly spoke about the advantages of spending the summer"

v1 = xlnet_en.encode(texts=[s1], pooling='reduce_mean')
v2 = xlnet_en.encode(texts=[s2], pooling='reduce_mean')

from sklearn.metrics.pairwise import cosine_similarity
dist = cosine_similarity(v1, v2)`

Comment: Let me check and comeback

Comment: hi Ashutosh, did you have the chance to check my code?

Comment: Hi. You are right, somehow the pre-trained weights are not loading up. Fixing this up. Sorry for the inconvenience.